# Suggestions on whether or not to close a topic

Tags: discussion

I am trying to be more involved in this community, since I have gotten much help from existing answers in the past, but I want to make sure I am following intended paths as well.

I have a post that I submitted an answer on, that has now been noted as from a student in a lab enviornment. I don't believe I missed anything that would have given me that impression when I answered it, but the comments later included that it was for school.

Should I submit a vote to close as soon as it is found out that it is not in a business enviornment? The issue is still very much valid outside of the education enviornment, and the answer may be found helpful to others in the community.

[Mapping Home folders using Powershell sets it in AD but does nothing else](https://serverfault.com/questions/848414/mapping-home-folders-using-powershell-sets-it-in-ad-but-does-nothing-else/)

Comment: I would leave it as is, as you need over 3k point to cast a close vote :) You can flag a moderator to get directly closed too, but on question where it's on a gray line I usually don't recommend it. (as even if a homework, sometime a good answer is valuable, even if the question is offtopic)

Comment: OK, flag is more what I meant, but you are correct. Again, I am green and still getting used to the process and culture. Thank you.

Comment: No worry :) I wasn't aware that close and flag was not the same at first too, kinda why I told you it, as I used to flag everything at first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please vote according to how you think this should be handled. If you agree that this is and should be off-topic, vote or flag as OT, but if you don't agree with this, just don't act or vote to reopen if closed or even actively lobby to change rules, e.g. in Meta Posts.

Change on sites like ours only happen if new blood comes in with a fresh and open mind, acting  according to how they would like the site to work.

Comment: OK, thank you for the opinion. I have had a much better experience on ServerFault vs trying to help over on SuperUser. My posts over there have been very heavily moderated, and referenced as doing it wrong. I also understand that they may need to be more picky, as their site has much more broad and basic needs. They have a LOT of questions come in that can easily be solved by short research.

Comment: Oh, we are very picky and many of our regular users (including me) have strong opinions about what is nor is not off-topic (sometimes erring on the side of too narrow maybe) and even more about "doing it right" - after all our target audience are more or less exclusively professionals. All that doesn't mean that you need to act and think the same, which is what I wanted to express in my answer.